# Running HTML/Javascript Dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, dom

I have a control on a web page that runs a call back function when a deposit is made.

In the backend the user can add script, images, iframes, etc and my program creates a javascript function with the same name as the controls deposit call back that runs the snippets of code the user entered into the backend (script, iframe, html, etc).

The function should run all the pieces of HTML/Javascript that a client entered into the CMS. I don't know in advance what the user will enter, it could be a script or an image or something else.

I'm having trouble running the snippets of HTML/Javascript.

1) I can't create a script element and add it to the DOM because it could be an image or something else entirely.

2) document.write works but it erases the page.

3) I can't use innerHTML, everything worked besides the scripts that I added dynamically.

4) I can't use a textNode because it doesn't run the scripts when I add them to the DOM.

Everytime I add it dynamically, I get the actual code printed to the string instead ofthe code running.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

p.s.

Here is an example of some HTML, if I could get this to work where the trackingCode might be an image or a script then that's my answer:

```
<head>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function test(pixelData){

var body= document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var trackingCode = '&lt;script type=\'text/javascript\'&gt;alert(\'[hi]\');&lt;/script&gt;';

var div = document.createElement('div')

trackingCode = trackingCode.replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&lt;/g,'<');
div.innerText = trackingCode;

document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(div);

body.appendChild(div);


}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
test();
</script>
<div id='whatever'>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the problem with innerHTML, do you see the script you type displayed as text or is it getting ignored?

Try using code=escape(code) before pasting it inside the element.

Comment: The script is displayed as text. When I escaped the javascript string it pasted it as encoded text but didn't run it.